# How to configure Mono Include Directory path with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mono, opensuse

I am trying to compile [this code](http://codepad.org/f9D5bg8u) on Open SuSE with GCC. I am getting "file not found error" for mono and related header files. I have installed mono and monodevelop lib. Please guide me on how to solve this error?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. Find where the required headers have been installed and pass that directory to `gcc` using the `-I` switch (such as `-I /usr/include/mono-2.0`). Don't forget to link to mono libraries (for example `-l mono-2.0`).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was because **libmono-2_0-devel library** was not installed on my machine. I was assuming that this will be pre-installed as I have installed mono. And also none of the document which talk about "Embedding Mono" mentioned this dependency.